# How to get npx to use latest bin script after publish

Tags: npm

I published a package and later on published another one.  Now when I try to run it using `npx example init` it keeps using the old script from the previous release and breaks.

How can I get npx to use the latest bin script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4108) with the npx cache.

To fix it delete the cache at `~/.npm/_npx`.

Comment: It is not a bug but expected behavior. Starting npx with @latest would be better but deleting the cache works too.

Comment: That's a good tip.  Next time I'll try `@latest`, that's probably even easier than deleting the cache.